How to save R interactive plots (e.g. plotly plots) in Linux?
I have created an interactive plot using plotly (with tooltips). I am using Linux command line interface.

Is it mandatory to use RStudio to save these interactive plots as they are (not as static plots)?
Can R (not R studio) do this, and if yes, how?
If I am running in Linux, how to save this kind of plot (e.g. as an html file or something smilar)?

Thanks
PS: I have tried htmlwidgets but it failed with the error:
 htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as_widget(p), file = "my_plot.html")
Error in pandoc_self_contained_html(file, file) :
  Saving a widget with selfcontained = TRUE requires pandoc. See here to learn more https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/install-pandoc.html


NOTE: htmlwidgets option works in Windows. My problem is with Linux.

does it work after you install pandoc?

I tried to install pandoc from source as I was not able to execute sudo.
https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/main/INSTALL.md#compiling-from-source
It still gives the same error message.

you dont have superuser access on your machine? is it a work machine? if so you may need to get your it/tech/systems team to install it for you

It is a work machine, and I'm working in linux servers.
